# xtable package: Skipping some rows in the output

Tags: r, dataframe, latex, xtable

In the `xtable` output, if I want some rows to have nothing in them I will put `NA`'s in the elements of the matrix that correspond to the row that I want skipped.

However this will lead to xtable output of something like `& & & & & & & & \\`. What I want to know is how do I make it so it's ONLY `\\` for that row that I wish to skip.

Comment: I don't think you can trick xtable into doing that. As a matter of interest: Why?

Comment: Because I generate a `HUGE` number of tables in my work. My method of doing so is in notepad++ where I have the rownames ready at the top of my .txt, and at the bottom of the .txt I copy my ~80 rows of xtable output, hold down `alt` (highlighting the table), cut (ctrl+X), go to the top of the .txt, left click on the right of the top-most rowname, spacebar 20 times, then CTRL+V. This way I can construct a very large table automatically with all the multicolumns in place. Except the `&&&&` get in the way because `\multicolumn` takes up too many columns.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it, then how can I edit the `xtable()` function? If I can edit the function then at the very end I can do a grep() search for `& & & &` and replace the rows (maybe).

Comment: You find the source code [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html). You could remove those empty rows entirely in `R` before `print( xtable( x ) )` but you _need_ the double backslash?

Comment: No, I don't. At each multicolumn spot I can put \\ after it in the template rownamnes.

Answer (score 5):

Still not sure whether I understand right but I give it a shot.

The most important assumption I'm making here is that your multicolumn rows in that template are always at the same spot. You use R to create a matrix or dataframe with no (useful) data in these rows.

For the purpose of this example, the multicolumn rows are 15, 30 and 60 of a dataframe of 80 rows, corresponding to your template of 80 rows.

What you could do: In `R`, eliminate those NA rows entirely, so that our dataframe now has only 77 rows.

You insert empty rows for your template via `xtable` with

```
> addtorow <- list()
> addtorow$pos <- list()
> addtorow$pos[[1]] <- c(14,29,59)
> addtorow$command <- "\\\\ \n"
> print( xtable( o ), add.to.row = addtorow, include.rownames=FALSE )
```

That should give you empty lines, no `&` but with `\\` and thus be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Harokitty Would be nice if you accept this one as an independent response to an independent question...

Comment: A most helpful solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want more flexibility you can build the table using a combination of `xtable` and `writeLines`. Let `xtable` write the first part to file (`print.xtable`, `file = "bla.txt"`), then write `\\` with `writeLines`, and continue with `xtable`. To prevent writing the header twice, set `only.contents` to `TRUE`. Do mind to set `append` equal to `TRUE` in your call to `print.xtable` and `writeLines`.